# Is there only one inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've read a book about linear algebra, which does not rush into introducing vectors as a list of numbers, i.e. looking at axioms only. Looking at it this way, it seemed that the dot product $\sum x_iy_i$ is not a definition of the inner product, but rather can be derived from the inner product axioms and is the only inner product (in a sense). Is this true?

If you just take the vector axioms and the inner product axioms, then vectors are just objects and there is no mention of lists of numbers. It is only when you decide on a *representation* with a basis, that lists of numbers appear. To me it seems, that you can always choose an orthonormal basis which implies $\sum x_iy_i$. Therefore this dot product can be derived from the axioms, it is not an arbitrary definition and it is the only one. Or in other words, if you make up a different equation for the inner product, then your basis is probably not orthonormal and you should have chosen a different basis instead.

Therefore, is $\sum x_iy_i$ the only inner product given that you choose an appropriate basis?

(What changes if you use a different signature for the multiplication, i.e. vectors square to -1 or 0? Is there something additional to consider if you use a complex vector space?)

Comment: You need an inner product to define what "orthonormal basis" means in the first place.

Comment: The complex inner product is not bilinear and denoted as $\sum x_i \bar{y_i}$. And you should be careful when it comes to infinite dimension.

Comment: The axioms of a real inner product are that of a symmetric bilinear form which is positive definite, which are all of the form $\sum_i x_i y_i$ in an appropriate basis.

Comment: @aschepler To define orthonormal basis I do not need the equation of the dot product.

Comment: @Zerox What changes in infinite dimensions?

Comment: Yes, you don't need the equation in terms of basis representations, but you do need that an inner product obeying the inner product axioms exists. So yes, we certainly don't want to say that the $\sum x_i y_i$ formula is a definition of inner product, since that would be circular. We can have different operators obeying the inner product axioms, and each follows the dot product formula when using a basis orthonormal according to that inner product, but not using a basis orthonormal according to the other. So "the only inner product in a sense" is a bit circular too.

Comment: @Gerenuk *To define orthonormal basis I do not need the equation of the dot product.* Yes, you do. Orthonormality of a basis is defined with respect to a chosen inner product.  By definition, a basis $\{e_0,e_1,...,e_n\}$ is called orthornomal if and only if $\langle{e_i,e_j}\rangle=\delta_{ij}.$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that a vector space $V$ is finite-dimensional, then, yes, if $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an inner product defined on $V$, then there is some basis $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ of $V$ (where $n=\dim V$) such that if $v=\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_kv_k$ and $w=\sum_{k=1}^n\beta_kv^k$, then$$\langle v,w\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k\beta_k.$$Simply take *any* basis $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n\}$ of $V$, apply the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to it, and then you will the basis $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ that you're after.

Comment: Thanks. So I can say "there is only one inner product"? What is different in infinite dimensions?

Comment: No, you cannot say “there is only one inner product”, because you may need to work with *two* inner products. In infinite dimension it's more complex. Depending upon the set theory that you are using, you may have infinite dimensional vector spaces with no bases.

Comment: And you never need more than two inner products? Could you please add an example to show how two non-isomorphic inner products are needed?
If I use a set theory such that I always have a basis, do at most two inner products exist in infinite vector spaces?

Comment: I never claimed that you never need more than two inner products. All I meant was that if you have more that one inner product and if you find a basis which is orthonormal with respect to one of them, it may well happen that it is not orthonormal with respect to the other ones. And even if all vector spaces have some basis, the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization only applies to *countable* bases.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answer that José Carlos Santos gave, if you have two inner products $\langle\cdot\,,\cdot\rangle_A$ and $\langle\cdot\,,\cdot\rangle_B,$ then you can have bases $E=\{e_0,e_1,...,e_n\}$ such that $F=\{f_0,f_1,...,f_n\}$ such that $E$ is orthonormal with respect to $\langle\cdot\,,\cdot\rangle_A$ and $F$ is orthonormal with respect to $\langle\cdot\,,\cdot\rangle_B,$ yet $E\neq{F},$ rendering $\langle\cdot\,,\cdot\rangle_A\neq\langle\cdot\,,\cdot\rangle_B.$ So, no, there is not "only one" inner product on any given vector space with a base. The inner products could be isomorphic, but need not be. As for how many inner products a vector space can have, it can have infinitely many, at least if the vector space has finite dimension.